# Faster way to check if two elements belong to the same coset in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

**Q:** Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ and $H=\langle 13\rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $13$.
Yes or No: do $24$ and $23$ belong to the same $H$-coset in $G$?

---

No; my reasoning:
Know that $2$ elements belong to the same coset if they are the same equivalence class and $\gcd(25,13)=1$, so 13 will generate the entire group $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$. $a \sim_Hb\iff -a+b\in H\implies23\sim_H24\iff-23+24\in H\implies1\in H \;\square$

Is my line of reasoning valid? How else could I have easily answer this "yes/no" question?

Comment: I find the sentence "[let] $H=\langle 25 \rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by 13" rather confusing.  Also, you mean by $G$ the entire *additive* group $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$, or the group of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ which are invertible (with respect to *multiplication*)?

Comment: `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Comment: Since $\gcd(25,13)=1$, $H=G$, so any two elements belong to the same coset.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ becomes $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ later. Which one is correct?

Comment: My apologies! I have made the edit from $\langle25\rangle$ to $\langle13\rangle$, and changed the $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$. It is late here :/

Comment: OK, thanks. Now, are we taking multiplication or addition? Because you appear to use both in your argument.

Comment: It was not specified in the question... though I presume it's additive by default for the set of integers modulo n (I think?).

Edit: I also changed $a^{-1}$ to $-a$ to make it clearer that I'm working with the additive inverse

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then the answer is yes, as @ArturoMagidin has argued in his comment above.

Comment: In fact $1 \in H$, as $H \ni 13 + 13 = 26 \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$.

Comment: Could you please further elaborate on the coprime claim? I am having trouble thinking of why that is significant in showing the same equivalence class.

Edit: I understand why $H=G$ is true in this case

Comment: @JasonXu: The order of $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is $n/\gcd(k,n)$.

Comment: I don't see how you got that either lol